# excel format: scale is 2 if value is larger than 1000

Tags: microsoft-excel

is there a way to define cell format for a number value, such that if it is more than 1000, then show only 2 digits on the right side of the decimal point, otherwise shows 4?

e.g. if the value is *1.259738*, shows as *1.2597*; if the value is *14579.9978*, shows as *14,579.00*

i'd like to have a solution via format, not modifying the cell formula as that would disturb computation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this Custom Format:

```
[>1000] 0.00;[<1000]0.0000
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

You need to use conditional formatting and multiple rules. I put the test data in J7 and J8 of 1.22345 and 10222.354 respectively.  I then selected the range J7 to J8 and with the active cell being J7 I entered the following formula in to conditional formatting:

```
=J7<10000   'Condition 1
```

and then

```
=J7>=10000  'Condition 2
```

[image]

In for each condition I selected the format button

[image]

From the numbers tab I selected Number in the category window and adjusted the number of decimal places to the desired amount.  If you wanted a different format browse for something that suits your needs or built your own custom format.

[image]

[image: POC]